# Вопрос по шаблонным методам C++

Tags: c++, классы, шаблоны-с++

Не получается пройти тестовый вопрос. Подскажите пожалуйста:

> Какие утверждения являются правильными?
>
> 1.Виртуальный метод не может быть шаблонным.
>   2.Конструктор по-умолчанию не может быть шаблонным.
>   3.inline метод не может быть шаблонным.
>   4.Статический метод не может быть шаблонным.
>   5.Константный метод не может быть шаблонным.
>   6.Деструктор не может быть шаблонным.

Comment: Может еще тест за вас пройти?

Comment: Только этот вопрос и не решен.

Comment: Было бы лучше, если бы вы высказали свои соображения по каждому из пунктов. В таком же виде - это не более как требование сделать работу за вас...

Comment: А что мешает попробовать?

Comment: Кстати, про шаблонный конструктор по-умолчанию интересный вариант. Конструктор сделать можно, а воспользоваться им - нет)

Comment: Я думаю, что 3 варианта точно сделать нельзя, конструктор по умолчанию, Деструктор, а также Виртуальный метод их точно нельзя сделать шаблонными, ну или они не будут работать. Только IDE пропускает все 6 вариантов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1.Виртуальный метод не может быть шаблонным.

Раздел 14.5.2 Member templates C++ стандарта

> 3 A member function template **shall not be** virtual

2.Конструктор по-умолчанию не может быть шаблонным

Конструктор по умолчанию - это не шаблонный конструктор без параметров либо с параметрами, которые имеют аргументы по умолчанию. Объявление любого конструктора класса в том числе и шаблонного конструктора препятствует неявному объявлению конструктора по умолчанию компилятором.

> 3.inline метод не может быть шаблонным

Спецификатор функции `inline` может быть применен к любому объявлению функции за исключение объявления в блоке кода. Более того функции, определенные в определении класса в том числе и шаблонные являются inline-функциями. Компилятор может проигнорировать этот спецификатор, либо, напротив, сделать функцию `inline`, то есть встраиваемой.

> 4.Статический метод не может быть шаблонным

Статический метод может быть шаблонным, как и любая другая функция.

> 5.Константный метод не может быть шаблонным

Константные методы класса могут быть шаблонными.

> 6.Деструктор не может быть шаблонным.

Раздел 14.5.2 Member templates C++ стандарта

> 2. ...A destructor **shall not be** a member template.

Comment: Спасибо, большое за развернутый ответ, репутацию вам добавить не могу, так как у самого ее нет.

Comment: @Sergu Можете просто выбрать ответ как лучший, тем самым пометив  свой вопрос как отвеченный, и вам, помимо моих 5 баллов добавится еще 2 балла.

Answer (score 1):

Да, да, нет, нет, нет, да.

Не могут быть шаблонными только очень специфичные методы...